# flutter: App tracking transparency for iOS app

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, usage-tracking

Do I need to provide "app tracking transparency" popup to my users. My app is free and does not use ads. However, I use Firebase analytics to determine usage and email (FB, google ,apple)to login the user.

I am getting ready to send an update for my to app store for approval and I don't want it to get rejected

Thanks for your help